# Error Using bndprice in Matlab's Financial Toolbox

Tags: matlab, finance

I'm new to Matlab and reading Numerical Methods in Finance so this should be a basic question.  The code in the book is as follows:

> > settle = '19-Mar-2000';
> >
> > maturity = '15-Jun-2015';
> >
> > face = 1000;
> >
> > couponRate = 0.05;
> >
> > yields = 0.01:0.01:0.20;
> >
> > [cleanPrices , accrInts] = bndprice(yields, couponRate, settle, maturity, 2, 0, [],[],[],[],[],face);

However it returns the following error

??? Error using ==> rdivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> bndprice at 218
PerDisc = 1./(1 + Yield./Frequency);

If I put in a single yield it works fine.  Any clue as to why there is an issue with the yields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're going to find this ridiculous, but you need to rearrange yields...

```
[cleanPrices , accrInts] = bndprice(yields', couponRate, settle, maturity, 2, 0, [],[],[],[],[],face);
```

ahh when the small things go wrong